# How to renew Kerberos ticket on spark yarn client mode?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, kerberos

I was using `Spark 1.6.0` to access data on Kerberos enabled HDFS by API `DataFrame.read.parquet($path)`.

My application is deployed as spark on yarn with client mode.
By default, Kerberos ticket expires every 24 hours. Everything works fine in the first 24 hours but failing to read files after 24 hours(or more, like 27 hours).

I have tried several ways to login and renew the ticket, doesn't work.

1. Set `spark.yarn.keytab` and `spark.yarn.principal` in `spark-defaults.conf`
2. Set `--keytab` and `--principal` in the `spark-submit` command line
3. Start a timer in code to call `UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser().checkTGTAndReloginFromKeytab()` every 2 hours.

**Error details are:**

```
WARN  [org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$1.run(Client.java:671)] - Couldn't setup connection for adam/cluster1@DEV.COM to cdh01/192.168.1.51:8032
DEBUG [org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1632)] - PrivilegedActionException as:adam/cluster1@DEV.COM (auth:KERBEROS) cause:java.io.IOException: Couldn't setup connection for adam/cluster1@DEV.COMto cdh01/192.168.1.51:8032
ERROR [org.apache.spark.Logging$class.logError(Logging.scala:95)] - Failed to contact YARN for application application_1490607689611_0002.
  java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Couldn't setup connection for adam/cluster1@DEV.COM to cdh01/192.168.1.51:8032; Host Details : local host is: "cdh05/192.168.1.41"; destination host is: "cdh01":8032;
```

Comment: How do you launch your Spark app ? with spark-submit ? Oozie ?

Comment: Submit Spark app with spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --principal xxx --keytab xxx

Comment: Maybe this link can help : https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/35261/what-is-correct-strategy-for-spark-streaming-kerbe.html

Comment: I have reviewed this link, the solution is just as my solution 2. From the documentation and our testing, it works on Spark on Yarn cluster mode, not client mode. See the link here: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/sg_spark_auth.html#concept_xqk_ghj_zt

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved.
It was caused by the wrong version of Hadoop lib.
In Spark 1.6 assembly jar, it refer to the old ver. of Hadoop lib, so I downloaded it again without build-in Hadoop lib, and referring to a third party Hadop 2.8 lib.
Then it just works.